# Using the maximum value of two equations from a mathematical expression in a pgf plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

Good afternoon everyone,

currently, I am making a graph to insert it into another document later on. It is a regression line in a dot cloud. (The dot cloud is represented by four coordinates in the code below.)

I have a problem with writing the formula for the regression line. It is supposed to be this formula:

[image: Regression formula]
Where ϑ is the x coordinate (I called it x in my code).

My question is, how do I tell LaTeX to always use the bigger value of the two linear equations? (resp. how do I write "max"?)

In the code I used \max, but I can not find out how exactly to use it. I also considered using an if-then-else command, but then I read that it does not work in a pgf environment.

Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\A{1.6}
\newcommand\B{-33}
\newcommand\C{8.6}
\newcommand\D{0.29}
\newcommand\MH{-0.08}
\newcommand\BH{1.6}
\newcommand\MW{-0.01}
\newcommand\BW{0.64}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[

width=\textwidth,
height=220pt,
axis lines=middle,
axis y line=left,
axis x line=bottom,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.8,
xmin=-20,
xmax=35,
]

\addplot+ [no marks, color=orange, domain=-15:30, samples=200]{(\max{\MH*x+\BH}{\MW*x+\BW}+((\A)/(1+((\B)/(x-40))^\C)+\D)/2}; %This is the regression line formula

\addplot [only marks, color=blue, mark options={scale=0.5}] coordinates { 
(18.50  ,   0.05)
(4.00   ,   0.07)
(-3.4   ,   0.3 )
(12     ,   0.4 ) 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: there is a formular for absolute value of 2 variables $$\max(m,n)=\dfrac{|m+n|+|m-n|}{2}$$, and TikZ/PGF has so called `abs` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is `max`, and the argument should be a comma separated list.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\A{1.6}
\newcommand\B{-33}
\newcommand\C{8.6}
\newcommand\D{0.29}
\newcommand\MH{-0.08}
\newcommand\BH{1.6}
\newcommand\MW{-0.01}
\newcommand\BW{0.64}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\textwidth,
height=220pt,
axis lines=middle,
axis y line=left,
axis x line=bottom,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.8,
xmin=-20,
xmax=35,
]

\addplot+ [no marks, color=orange, domain=-15:30, samples=200]
{max(\MH*x+\BH,\MW*x+\BW)+((\A)/(1+((\B)/(x-40))^\C)+\D)/2}; %This is the regression line formula

\addplot [only marks, color=blue, mark options={scale=0.5}] coordinates {
(18.50  ,   0.05)
(4.00   ,   0.07)
(-3.4   ,   0.3 )
(12     ,   0.4 )
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]